# Editable text and input field in same html function (Textarea + input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

I have a text where most of the text is pre-filled which is the "most" common text that the user will have and a input field where the user have to enter the date. 
I've tried using summernote with a input field which doesn't work very well.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the first text is the default text but can also be edited by the user. The input field and default text has to be in one as it should create a fluent text and the input field will be checked in some other places if the user has inserted the info or not.

Comment: You appear to be asking for an `<input>` to be nested inside a `<textarea>`.   Would require a lot of hacking about, especially to create the 'fluent' part when you cursor around or select all and it selects both.  Might be easier to go with a tokenised approach.   (eg "Please fill in the date {{YYYY-MM-DD}}" then check for `"{{"`)

Comment: Hmm.. never thought about that.. the thing is that that input field value will be used separately in other places and depending on if it's filled or not, a check for feedback is shown beside the field for the user to see where he have to fill in and not. Maybe something else than textarea/input that might work? Could it be possible to validate the text for YYYY-MM-DD with javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the textarea element and specify `type="date"` within the element. This combined with a placeholder and the keyword "required" would do the trick. You could also separate the year, month and date into their own fields.

Alternatively if this is for a PHP form you could always get the date automatically using the PHP below.

Example 1:

```html
<textarea  name="example" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required ></textarea>
```

Example 2:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: I can't see how this solves OP's requirement of being able to change the text around the date and enter a date within an explicit field.  (both text and date to be editable).